# bash comparison of integer always returns true?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have the following simple bash script. for some reason it always returns true.

```
#!/bin/bash
service=hhvm
status=($(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l))
if [[ $status -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "starting $service"
    service hhvm start
else
    echo "$service running"
fi
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20248/discussion-on-question-by-r3wt-bash-comparison-of-integer-always-returns-true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final script that worked. [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20240/discussion-between-r3wt-and-kasiya)

```
#!/bin/bash
service=hhvm
if ! (($(ps -ef | grep -v "grep"| grep "$service" | wc -l))) ; then
    echo "starting $service"
    service hhvm start
else
    echo "$service is running"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to help me. I owe ya 1.. or 2 lol. Have a good day. :-]

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it stopped working again. weird. maybe by dev box got hacked, who knows

Answer (score 2):

```
foo=3
if [[ $foo -eq 0 ]]; then     # -eq: equal
  echo "foo equals 0"
else
  echo "foo is not equal to 0"
fi
```

Comment: still returns true...

Comment: You might want to add a small explanation

Comment: @r3wt I get: `foo is not equal to 0`, just like @KasiyA 's suggestion

Comment: @Jacob it always returns "foo equals 0"

Comment: @r3wt: Sorry, your bash is broken.

Comment: @r3wt That means your foo is equal zero.

Comment: @KasiyA nope, just checked

Comment: thanks for the attempt man, i went ahead and upvoted you for the effort.